# How to Maintain Parameter name in Java?

Tags: java, web-services, parameters

I have created a Web Service in Java and I have declared my methods in the Interface.

```
int Add(int number1,int number2,int number3)
```

but when I consume the same in the client I get the parameter name as

```
int Add(int arg0,int arg1,int arg3)
```

How can I have the same name in client as I have declared in Interface.After creating client proxy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is that Java stores parameter names in the binary .class file for classes, but *not* for interfaces. So, if you generate a WSDL from an SEI, and you haven't annotated the names, you will see these.

The easiest solution is to add `@WebParam` annotations to all of the parameters. In that annotations, you can repeat the name, and then it will be in the WSDL, and then it will be in your generated client.